# laravel using get() with specific role

Tags: php, laravel

6 projects 
and there is user model and this is a method in user model

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

Everything is working fine when I am using get() in laravel like this

```
User::get();
```

It returns all users. 
My question is, is there a way to write method in the model that can return users with conditions, not all users,
like this

```
public function setRoleToGetData()
{
  $user  = Auth::user()->getSex // getSex is method in the model 
  if($user == 1)
    return users in the whole program like this 
    User::where('user_sex','=',1)->get();
  else
    // return the reverse 
}
```

i dont want to write `where('user_sex','=',1) in every time i want to get users`
thanks

Comment: there are global scopes for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for scopes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes

From the docs:

> Local scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application

Example:

```
public function scopePopular($query)
{
    return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
}
```

Then use as

```
SomeModel::popular()->get();
```